# Arch linux: My display driver chip keeps bricking

Tags: xorg, display, x-server, intel-graphics, thinkpad

I use `arch-thinkpad 6.1.7-arch1-1` on `Lenovo x390 yoga` with `Intel WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620]`. I also use i3wm on xorg. Something like every two days my built-in screen display goes black without any warning. Even backlight turns off. Everything else still runs and works. If I have an external monitor connected it will still work. *Arandr* will not show build in display as an output device.

[image]

When I reboot it plays "melody". This melody is POST code. I decoded it and it is `011028` which stands for "*No display*".

The only way to make the display work again is to unscrew the case of a laptop, disconnect the battery and hold the power button for around 1 minute. Then when I connect back to battery and display works for another 2 days.

What is happening? How can I diagnose it? How can I fix it?
Thank you for your help

PS: If you need any more information I will gladly provide it.